# How do I simulate 1mbps and 3mbps using jmeter? What would be my CPS value?

Tags: performance, networking, jmeter, bandwidth, simulate

I am tryng to simulate 3 users with different bandwidth of mobile data(1mbps) and Wifi(3mbps). How can I achieve this using jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

The formula for cps calculation is:

```
cps = (target bandwidth in kbps * 1024) / 8
```

For `3mbps` , cps value would be: `(3072 * 1024) / 8 = 393216`

Some popular bandwidth presets are given in this article : [How to Simulate Different Network Speeds in Your JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-simulate-different-network-speeds-your-jmeter-load-test)